Twilio Flow with Split Based On... boolean argument
Considering widgets.get_sms_opt.parsed.SmsOpt is can be either true, false (boolean values), or null, like in:
    "widgets": {
        "get_sms_opt": {
            "status_code": 200,
            "content_type": "application/json",
            "parsed": {
                "SmsOpt": false
            },
            "body": "{\"SmsOpt\":false}"
        },
        ...

and that I want to have a "Split Based On..." widget with a different transition for each of the different true, false and null values.
This is what I've done below and it's selecting the "If no condition matches" transition when the value is false, instead of the "If value equal_to false" transition as I was expecting.
Will the "Equal To" predicate work with booleans? From the documentation it's not clear which kind of comparison it's done for different types of values.
{
  "name": "sms_opt_split",
  "type": "split-based-on",
  "transitions": [
    {
      "next": "send_opt_in_prompt",
      "event": "noMatch"
    },
    {
      "next": "send_main_menu",
      "event": "match",
      "conditions": [
        {
          "friendly_name": "If value equal_to true",
          "arguments": [
            "{{widgets.get_sms_opt.parsed.SmsOpt}}"
          ],
          "type": "equal_to",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "event": "match",
      "conditions": [
        {
          "friendly_name": "If value equal_to false",
          "arguments": [
            "{{widgets.get_sms_opt.parsed.SmsOpt}}"
          ],
          "type": "equal_to",
          "value": "false"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  ...


Yes, you can check boolean variables in the "Split based on" widget. Follow an example, in my Flow I have a function that basically will return, "true", "false" or "null", based on a parameter that I sent, and in the "checkVariable" widget I can check specific results, "true" or "false", and if the response is "null" will catch on "No Conditions Matches"

I hope that it can help you :D
